# How do I convert this nginx rule to .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How do I convert the following Nginx rule into .htaccess?

`location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ { try_files $uri/ /image-proxy.php$is_args$args; }`